# How to backup user files automatically via rsync?

Tags: rsync

I need to take incremental backup of users files which is located in the following location automatically using a cron job. Could anyone explain the procedure to take backup using rsync in detail pls?

**Location: /home/user1/Desktop/**

Note: The backup should be saved as follows, if the system IP is 172.29.36.10 the backupfile should be named as user10 and so on. How to acheive this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and type: `man rsync`

But seriously, if you're just wanting to do a backup that copies what you currently have in ~/Desktop to that location and not store any backlog or anything like that you could use:

`rsync -azve ssh --delete /home/user1/Desktop 172.29.36.10:/Desktop/backup/folder`

You'll have to install openssh-server on the receiving side though. Or you could create a script in /etc/init.d to start `rsync --deamon` on the remote machine at boot and remove the `e ssh` part

Here's a breakdown of the options: `-a` archive mode (recurse directories and keep permissions, etc), `-v` verbose mode, `-e ssh` use the SSH protocol for the transfer, `--delete` delete extraneous files on the receiving side.

Comment: That's assuming he has an rsync daemon running on the other machine. (-a is the same as -rt [more specifically -rlptgoD]). He could use -u, but I think it's unnecessary unless it's a folder used by somebody else as well.

Comment: Greetings: `rsync --progress --hurtz /directory/to/backup validUser@172.29.36.10:/destination/for/backup/` Keep in mind that you wont be able to rsync without being prompted for a password, so to rsync without having to type a password you can read this tut: **http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html**

Comment: the **rsync** utility is installed in Ubuntu by default.

Comment: I completely forgot about the fact that he's doing it through a cron job... that might be an issue. Good link. That's how I reach my machine for cron jobs as well.

Comment: But it's not enabled as a daemon. It needs an /etc/rsyncd.conf which isn't provided. And rsync's a picky beast that I only use when absolutely necessary, so I avoid dealing with it at all costs HAHA