# Save Ubuntu Backups in many locations

Tags: 15.04, backup

I would like to know if it's possible (or is planned to be possible) to be able to save the system backups in many locations. Let me explain my problem:
I have a disk with my photos and an exactly the same disk for it's backup, they are called Photos and PhotosCopy. I configured Ubuntu backup from Photos to PhotosCopy.
Now I want to make a backup of my /home directory in another storage (not in PhotosCopy).
I can't find a way do do it. Any ideas?

Comment: "rsync" is the command you want to use if you talk about copying files to other locations. Even remote is possible. Example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105314/how-to-backup-user-files-automatically-via-rsync